# Cannot host ASP.NET MVC application in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, configuration, iis-5

I have created a virtual directory on the IIS (IIS 5.1 that's what i'm using). when i try t o run the applciation from my browser using the URL

**http://localhost/sitename** .

i'm able to see the initial landing page . But when i force a controller action call like this .

**http://localhost/controllername/actionMethodName**

i receive the 404(file not found error). But when i'm running the application from the asp.net development server (intergrated with VS ) everyhting works fine.

what may be the reason. i have set impersonate in web.config and enabled anonymous access  in the IIS .

any thoughts/ suggestions

thanks,

vijay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried http://localhost/sitename/controllername/action?

Edit: You could try these solutions:

- [ASP.NET MVC and IIS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712/mvc-net-and-iis-5)
- [Deploy ASP.NET MVC on IIS 5.1 (Windows XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301359/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5-1-windows-xp)