# .NET MVC links on IIS 5.1 produces 404 error when Wildcard mapping is implemented

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404, iis-5

I have a simple MVC site with ActionLinks to content such as "FAQ" and "About Us". I have set up the virtual directory in IIS Manager and set the mapping (no wildcard mapping option in IIS 5.1) for ".*" to point to aspnet_isapi.dll. This allowed me to bring up the home page and view it. However, when I click on any of the action links, I get a 404 error. I have tried adding code for a new route to append .aspx to the controller name

[ASP.NET MVC and IIS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712/mvc-net-and-iis-5)

I know this is redundant but figured i would give a shot before bothering everyone on SO. I am still experiencing the problem and cant seem to figure out what it is. I was hoping that someone might have a suggestion or two for me. Thanks in advance for any help.

FYI - My site runs fine under Cassini, it only blows up when I try and hit it directly through localhost/SITE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I didnt have the "Check file exists" box unchecked in the mapping for either ".*" or ".mvc". Once I did this everything worked. I was also able to remove the routes for the .mvc mapping as it works fine without it.