# URL Routing not working when set as Virtual directory under IIS.But works in VS IDE

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

I have an ASP.NET web application(WebForms,Not MVC) developed in VS 2008 and i have implemented ASP.NET web forms URL routing by following this link https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx#postadlink 
It works pretty good when i run it on the Visual studion IDE.But does not works when i created a site under my IIS (IIS 5.1 in XP) and deployed the same files there.I have set ASP.NET version as 2.0 in the Properties window of my application too.But does not work. Any idea Why ? Is there anything else to be setup ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured IIS with a wildcard route or are you using an appropriate extension, rather than extensionless routes?

[ASP.NET MVC and IIS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712/mvc-net-and-iis-5)

Comment: Yes, I have tried the solution which is given on the above link 
routes.Add(new Route("VacancyDetail.mvc.aspx/{VacancyRef}", new VacancyDetailHandler())
            {
                Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "VacancyDetail" })
            });

but it is not working.It gives me an errro message: The resource cannot be found.