# Page not found error while hosting ASP.NET MVC on iis 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows, web-hosting, iis-5

I am trying to host ASP.NET MVC on iis 5. I have tried adding wild card mapping. but is not working. I had hosted this before, but now i don't remember the settings that i need to do to host the same on iis 5. 
PLease let me know some of the links/ give me some suggestions where i can solve this issue..

Comment: What is the great reason to use IIS version 5?

Comment: Some existing SO answers should get you going on this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301359/deploy-asp-net-mvc-on-iis-5-1-windows-xp  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712/asp-net-mvc-and-iis-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this thread here on SO: [ASP.NET MVC and IIS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57712/asp-net-mvc-and-iis-5)

Comment: @Dan-Diplo - I had already noted this link in my comment to @nimi as a duplicate question.... :-)